# Why is my ajax post posting in the correct table but it posts all id's on page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Ok so this is kind of wierd so I will try to explain it as easy as possible. My admin.php pulls in all the content from a pending database and then puts into foreach loop. Example: I have 2 stories in pending table and my admin page shows both of them and each have different Id's. Whenever I click to add one to school1 table it puts both stories in school1 instead of just the 1 story I clicked on.

admin.php:

```
foreach ($list as $rs) {
    ?>
        <?php echo '<p>id:'.$rs['id']. '</p><br>';?>
        <!--school 1 table add--><?php echo 'school1<a href="#" class="add_button" id="del-'.$rs["id"]. '"><img src="images/add.png"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;';?>
        <!--school 2 table add--><?php echo 'school2<a href="#" class="add_button_school2" id="del-'.$rs["id"]. '"><img src="images/add.png"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;';?>      
    <?php
  }
```

my ajax calls in the same page:

```
//##### Send add Ajax request to responseadd.php ######### - School 1 post
$("body").on("click", " .add_button", function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var clickedID = this.id.split('-'); //Split ID string (Split works as PHP explode)
     var DbNumberID = clickedID[1]; //and get number from array
     var myData = 'recordToDelete='+ DbNumberID; //build a post data structure

    $('#item_'+DbNumberID).addClass( "sel" ); //change background of this element by adding class
    $(this).hide(); //hide currently clicked delete button

        jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
        url: "responseadd.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
        dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
        data:myData, //Form variables
        success:function(response){
            //on success, hide  element user wants to delete.
            $('#item_'+DbNumberID).fadeOut();
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            //On error, we alert user
            alert(thrownError);
        }
        });
});

//##### Send add Ajax request to responseaddschool2.php ######### - School 2 post
$("body").on("click", " .add_button_school2", function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var clickedID = this.id.split('-'); //Split ID string (Split works as PHP explode)
     var DbNumberID = clickedID[1]; //and get number from array
     var myData = 'recordToDelete='+ DbNumberID; //build a post data structure

    $('#item_'+DbNumberID).addClass( "sel" ); //change background of this element by adding class
    $(this).hide(); //hide currently clicked delete button

        jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
        url: "responseaddschool2.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
        dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
        data:myData, //Form variables
        success:function(response){
            //on success, hide  element user wants to delete.
            $('#item_'+DbNumberID).fadeOut();
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            //On error, we alert user
            alert(thrownError);
        }
        });
});
```

Note: I do have 2 php files but that will change soon since we are cleaning up the code. But I will still have the same issues since it looks like there is nothing wrong with the php but instead the ajax calls sending that data.